# How to install toolchain and custom GDB in VSCode to debug remote target

Tags: visual-studio-code, gdb, vscode-remote, toolchain, gdbserver

I am trying to debug a cross compiled remote target with GDB.

The target OS only has gdbserver so I have to use a custom GDB from my WSL host to remotely attach to it. The target is cross compiled with a custom Yocto distro toolchain, which is *only installed in the same shell session I build it in*.

I can install the toolchain with a helper script for a shell session, and launch the custom GDB with `$GDB`.

```
./toolchain-helper.sh
whereis $GDB
/opt/toolchains/.../sysroots/usr/bin/x86_64-special-linux-gdb
$GDB
(gdb) target remote 192.168.0.100:9999
```

I'm trying to use VSCode debugger and its GUI to make debugging eaiser. I can't figure out how to configure launch.json to run `toolchain-heler.sh` and use `$GDB`. Is it possible to do?

VSCode Version: 1.75.1

Native Debug Version: 0.26.1